# What would Negative Energy act like?

Tags: energy

So I heard that if you want to make a wormhole you need negative energy. What is special about Negative Energy that allows it to do that? What are the properties of Negative Energy compared to normal energy?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as negative energy, except in the mathematical sense of representing a deficit of (positive) real energy.

It's just like having money (real, positive), where having it in a financial sense is called "long", and if you owe money, then you are short (of a few bucks), but the actual money is always real and positive.

Comment: Casimir effect?

Comment: I don't think this is true in general relativity, even if it'd be true in Newtonian physics--what energy you define to be "zero" is not arbitrary, a universe with zero energy density everywhere would be a flat spacetime. And because of mass/energy equivalence, negative energy would be equivalent to negative mass, which in both Newtonian gravity and relativity would exert a repulsive gravitational force on positive mass, although it would itself be attracted to positive mass (see [here](http://www.npl.washington.edu/AV/altvw14.html)).